# Use me well and I am everybody

Tags: riddle

One more who/what am I:

> Use me well and I am everybody,
> Scratch my back and I am nobody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could it be a *reflective image* like a **mirror**, when you appear in front of it, it shows you or whoever is there (everybody). But if you have **scratched** it, it becomes blurry or not clear and off no use.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: there could be many more... like a **camera** would that be right too then.

Comment: Ok, then add another answer ;-)

Comment: hahhahaha.... ;)

Comment: Well, Actually I thought that a mirror had a mirror paper in it's back. If you scratch that, the mirror can't reflect.